# Core web vitals still failing on LCP

Tags: core-web-vitals

We fixed a lot of site issues as we had a LCP score of more than 4s on desktop.

On Google’s page speed test, we saw a new speed of 1 second on desktop.

However, after 28 days of validation, we’ve just received a fail for the issue on desktop.

I don’t understand. According to Google’s own tool we shouldn’t be failing.

What do we need to do?

The website is https://www.curveball-media.co.uk/

We made changes to the site and expected the validation to pass.